# macro variable in data frame name using r

Tags: r

I would like to use the concept of macro variable from SAS in r but cannot seem to find the right code.
It would normally look like this in SAS where I change the name once and it replicates many places.

```
%LET CITY=NewYork; 
Query_&NAME_V01 <- &NAME[,1:3]
Query_&NAME_V01 <- &NAME[1:10,]
```

I tried using the `quote` and `noquote` function but I always end up with the this error message: `target of assignment expands to non-language object`.

Comment: You need to edit to make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610).

Comment: Is what you want to do possible? Yes.  But it's a bad way to go about the problem.  Try explaining the goal you want to achieve and we can help you do it in a better way.

Comment: I essentially want to speed up the work by no changing manually those variable for ad-hoc analysis.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had to learn some SAS and trust me I cannot think to something like SAS macros in R. At least not something that it is as easy to use.
But trust me, R is much more powerful, you have just to think like R (and most of programming languages nowadays) and not like SAS.

Put your data in a list and use a for loop here an example that print the colnames  of dataframe(cat is just the print function)

```
example<-list(airquality,iris,mtcars)
for(i in 1:length(example)){
  cat(colnames(example[[i]]),"\n")
}
```

You could use non standard evaluation to imitate SAS behaviour, here a reference http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html but trust me It is something that it does not fit to a newbie. Even R experienced users struggle with this.